# android Fatal Exception: AsyncTask #5

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, image-compression

I'm having a problem with my asynctask code. here is my code. it said that it couldn't read row 0.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        Uri filePath = data.getData();
        try {

            new ImageCompressionAsyncTask(getApplicationContext()).execute(String.valueOf(filePath));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class ImageCompressionAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    Context mContext;

    public ImageCompressionAsyncTask(Context context){
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String filePath = SiliCompressor.with(mContext).compress(params[0]);
        return filePath;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

        File imageFile = new File(s);
        compressUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);

        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), compressUri);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

here is the logcat of the project.

```
 08-01 08:32:50.181 28589-28920/ground.project.com.undergroundproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
                                                                                   Process: ground.project.com.undergroundproject, PID: 28589
                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
                                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
                                                                                       at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
                                                                                       at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:438)
                                                                                       at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
                                                                                       at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:114)
                                                                                       at com.iceteck.silicompressorr.SiliCompressor.getRealPathFromURI(SiliCompressor.java:322)
                                                                                       at com.iceteck.silicompressorr.SiliCompressor.compressImage(SiliCompressor.java:163)
                                                                                       at com.iceteck.silicompressorr.SiliCompressor.compress(SiliCompressor.java:59)
                                                                                       at ground.project.com.undergroundproject.UploadPhotoActivity$ImageCompressionAsyncTask.doInBackground(UploadPhotoActivity.java:124)
                                                                                       at ground.project.com.undergroundproject.UploadPhotoActivity$ImageCompressionAsyncTask.doInBackground(UploadPhotoActivity.java:113)
                                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
                                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

i have used the silicompressor library in order to compress the image i will upload in the server. but this happens. appreciate the help that i could get here. thank you guys.

Comment: do u use a db? and store images or access images?

Comment: no sir. i dont use any db

Comment: i access images through intent